# Filtering by comparing two streams one-on-one in jq

Tags: stream, compare, jq

I have streams

```
{
    "key": "a",
    "value": 1
}
{
    "key": "b",
    "value": 1
}
{
    "key": "c",
    "value": 1
}
{
    "key": "d",
    "value": 1
}
{
    "key": "e",
    "value": 1
}
```

And

```
 (true,true,false,false,true)
```

I want to compare the two **one-on-one** and only print the object if the corresponding boolean is `true`.

So I want to output

```
{
    "key": "a",
    "value": 1
}
{
    "key": "b",
    "value": 1
}
{
    "key": "e",
    "value": 1
}
```

I tried (https://jqplay.org/s/GGTHEfQ9s3)

```
filter:
. as $input | foreach (true,true,false,false,true) as $dict ($input; select($dict))

input:
{
    "key": "a",
    "value": 1
}
{
    "key": "b",
    "value": 1
}
{
    "key": "c",
    "value": 1
}
{
    "key": "d",
    "value": 1
}
{
    "key": "e",
    "value": 1
}
```

But I get output:

```
{"key":"a","value":1}
{"key":"a","value":1}
null
{"key":"b","value":1}
{"key":"b","value":1}
null
{"key":"c","value":1}
{"key":"c","value":1}
null
{"key":"d","value":1}
{"key":"d","value":1}
null
{"key":"e","value":1}
{"key":"e","value":1}
null
```

Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to read in the streams as arrays, use `transpose` to match their items, and `select` by one and output the other:

```sh
jq -s '[.,[(true,true,false,false,true)]] | transpose[] | select(.[1])[0]' objects.json
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/JZLaMX_ys6)

Another approach would be to read in the streams as arrays, convert the booleans array into those `indices` where conditions match, and use them to reference into the objects array:

```sh
jq -s '.[[(true,true,false,false,true)] | indices(true)[]]' objects.json
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/veYzppN4rA)

The same approach but using `nth` to reference into the `inputs` stream requires more precaution, as the successive consumption of stream inputs demands the provision of relative distances, not absolute positions to `nth`. A conversion can be implemented by successively checking the position of the next `true` value using `index` and a `while` loop:

```sh
jq -n 'nth([true,true,false,false,true] | while(. != []; .[index(true) + 1:]) | index(true) | values; inputs)' objects.json
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/pENuwzbX0T)

One could also use `reduce` to directly iterate over the boolean values, and just `select` any appropriate `input`:

```sh
jq -n 'reduce (true,true,false,false,true) as $dict ([]; . + [input | select($dict)]) | .[]' objects.json
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/-9w6ycdDJv)

A solution using `foreach`, like you intended, also would need the `-n` option to not miss the first item:

```sh
jq -n 'foreach (true,true,false,false,true) as $dict (null; input | select($dict))' objects.json
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/bN8IjekfrZ)

Comment: third solution gives {"key":"a","value":1} {"key":"c","value":1} {"key":"e","value":1} which is wrong. thanks a lot btw.

Comment: @LoganLee You are right! I didn't notice that `nth`, when given a stream of indices, always just references into the so far unconsumed `inputs`. I fixed it by converting the absolute indices to relative ones. Thank you for spotting that glitch.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, each invocation of jq can currently handle at most one external JSON stream. This is not usually an issue unless both streams are very large, so in this answer I'll focus on a solution that scales.  In fact, the amount of computer memory required is miniscule no matter how large the streams may be.

For simplicity, let's assume that:

- demon.json is a file consisting of a stream of JSON boolean values (i.e., not comma-separated);
- object.json is your stream of JSON objects;
- the streams have the same length;
- we are working in a bash or bash-like environment.

Then we could go with:

```
paste -d '\t' demon.json <(jq -c . objects.json) | jq -n '
  foreach inputs as $boolean (null; input; select($boolean))'
```

So apart from the startup costs of `paste` and `jq`, we basically only need enough memory to hold one of the objects in objects.json at a time. This solution is also very fast.

Of course, if objects.json were already in JSONL (JSON-lines) format, then the first call to jq above would not be necessary.